# What would be the best validation criteria for normal text fields

Tags: reactjs

What would be the best validation criteria for normal text input fields which will block special characters, quotes and such kind. 
I am using DataTables and it gives errors if it finds some special characters. So I want to reject such data.

Using React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally validation criteria based on what kind of data you want to going to get...so think and decide yourself..
my suggestion is to use http://validatejs.org/ lib for validate string....